# Which investment option provides the best income tax benefit? [Canada]

Tags: canada, income-tax, tax-deduction, investing

If I have $100 to invest and I have the ability to choose from the following:

1. GIC at 3% interest
2. Shares that I might later sell at $105
3. Shares that pay a dividend of $3

Assuming that the period is about a year (same tax year), which would be the best option from an income tax deduction perspective?  Note: this is a slight variation of [this](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/1401/how-do-i-use-investments-to-lower-my-taxes-us) question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leaving aside the utility of investing in shares for a one-year term, and therefore also effectively leaving aside the risk that in #2 the shares might only be worth $95, the question then becomes, which type of income is taxed least:

- Interest income
- Capital Gains
- Dividend income

The first part is simple, Interest income is fully taxed as income, so it is always the least efficient, from a tax perspective, so it is immediately let out.

For the other two, the rate at which capital and dividend is effectively taxed depends upon your tax brackets, and also province.  I found this cool [calculator](http://www.walterharder.ca/MarginalTaxRateCalculator.asp) that you can play with to see the marginal tax rate on the various types of income.

Comment: I took a look at that calculator; where is the definition of the difference between "large corp" and "small business" dividends? Is the former just any company that is registered as a provincial/national "corporation"?

Comment: By my understanding "large-corp" would be normal shareholder dividends paid out by any incorporated company.  Small-business would be where you are more directly part-owner, but not of an incorporated company.